# Creating new point geometry MapInfo File (TAB) in PyQGIS

Tags: qgis-3, mapinfo, pyqgis-3, tab

I am trying to create empty tab file with different approach's.

1st approach

```py
fn = r'E:\data\spilce.tab'
shpfields = QgsFields()
id = QgsField('id', QVariant.Int)
shpfields.append(id)
gtp = QgsWkbTypes.Point
cr = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:4326')
QgsVectorFileWriter(fn, 'utf-8', shpfields, gtp, cr, 'MapInfo File')
```

2nd approach

```py
fn = r'E:\data\spilce.tab'
cr = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:4326')
ipointlayer = QgsVectorLayer("Point?crs='EPSG:4326'", "temporary_points", "memory")
ipointlayer.dataProvider().addAttributes([QgsField("Id", QVariant.String)])
ipointlayer.updateFields()
QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(ipointlayer, fn, 'utf-8', cr, 'MapInfo File')
```

Above codes creating non-geometry tab files.

How to create Point Geometry TAB file?

Comment: Not sure how. Issue seems not related to PyQGIS itself. Created a tab file not empty by exporting a shp to Mapinfo Tab. Then, opened the new file, started editing and removed all features from the new layer, saved changes, removed the layer. Then, tried to add it again and QGIS considered this empty layer as attribute layer.

Comment: Tested the same code with Shapefile and GPKG. Driver specific but did not found explanation at the moment